# Porque cuando pongo una imagen en html se baja la calidad?

Tags: html, web, imagen

Cuando inserto una imagen en html se baja la calidad a la hora de ver la web. Si alguien me lo puede decir lo agradeceria

Comment: Debes colocar el código mínimo necesario para verificar el porqué ves mal la imagen en el navegador, al menos el html y css.

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada, sugiero leas [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás intentando redimensionar la imagen con CSS o atributos (height, width) de HTML, la baja calidad se debe a que estás tratando de modificar las dimensiones originales y es normal que la imagen se deforme. Para prevenir esto puedes hacer lo siguiente

```css
img {
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Esto hará que la imagen sea siempre la original aunque se cambien las dimensiones de esta.

#### Puede ser de utilidad

- [CSS object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)
- [Object fit - CSS (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)